# How can I use a blade directive within the livewire wire:click template directive?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I am currently on Laravel 8 with Livewire. I know it may sound a bit noob but please help me substituting `@json` instead of `json_encode` within the livewire template directive i.e. `wire:click`.

Here is the whole line of code for follwing.

```
wire:click="$emit('deleteUserBulk', {{ json_encode($selected) }} )"
```

Comment: `$emit('deleteUserBulk', '@json($selected)')"`

Comment: @IGP It ain't working, It isn't passing the data but whereas `{{ json_encode($selected) }}` works seamlessly.

Comment: You're right. After checking it out myself I came to the conclusion you must use `{{ json_encode }}`.  {{ json_encode }} escapes the output. @json does not. @json is meant to be used for js components.